# Вопрос про корректность выполнения ТЗ

Tags: java

Всем привет!

Ребят, вопрос смешной, но я новичек в Java, просто возникла паранойя.

Мне дали небольшую тестовую задачу на собеседовании, где надо реализовать сервис на основе **выданного интерфейса**.

В ходе выполнения задачи я сделал свои собственные исключения MyException и кое где у меня они вызываются, соответственно, в этих методах добавилось throws.

Т.е. было так:

```
public interface TaskInterface {

/**
* some Method1
*/

public Method1 (String param1, String param2);

....
....

}
```

а стало так:

```
public interface TaskInterface {

/**
* some Method1
*/

public Method1 (String param1, String param2) throws MyException;

....
....

}
```

**Насколько это может быть критично для проверяющих?**

Т.е. грубо говоря дали одно, а я написал для немного другого... т.е. на лицо нарушение выполнения оглашённого ТЗ. Или не так все страшно?

Спасибо!

Comment: Мне кажется, стоило не переписывать заданный интерфейс, а написать свой, наследующий от заданного, и там переопределить эти методы, не?

Comment: Как-то это странно выглядит...
Т.е. просто создаю новый newInterface extends TaskInterface и пошло поехало? 
Это и в правду так нужно делать в данной ситуации?

Comment: Как мне кажется, прежде всего, вопрос в том, можно ли было реализовать то, что требовалось по заданию, пользуясь только выданным интерфейсом? вы уверены, что все ваши изменения, которые вы внесли в интерфейс - точно нужны и что без них никак было не обойтись? если да, то в таком случает создать своей интерфейс на основе заданного кажется мне более кошерным решением. ну, чисто по моим впечатлениям.

Comment: для того чтоб ответить на вопрос что делать с ошибкой нужно знать какой результат выполнения метода. если смотреть на указаный вами дизайн то возвращаемого результата вообще нет (т.е. он не указан). дальше есть несколько вариантов:  
1) выбрасываем exception наверх 
2) пишем в лог
3) предусмотреть возврат ошибки как часть ответа (если метод возвращает какой-то обьект)

p.s. я надеюсь все же в вашем ТЗ указан результат выполнения функции, если вы незаметили и не уточнили это вам минус

Comment: да, я забыл указать в вопросе) разумеется там есть тип возвращаемого значения

Comment: Лучше всего посоветоваться с заказчиком. Возможно, ваши изменения в интерфейс ему понравятся.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Я бы поступил хитро. Свои исключения `MyException` я бы наследовал от `RuntimeException`, тогда его не нужно включать в сигнатуру метода - тогда вы сохраните и требование тестера в реализации конкретного интерфейса, ну и свой эксепшн будете иметь.

Переделывать интерфейс не есть айс - частенько ведь интерфейс приходит от внешней либы или является частью спецификации (как например `Servlet`)

Comment: Да, большое вам спасибо за толковый совет. Так и сделаю :)